# Confusion about algorithm

Tags: algorithm

[image]
[image]

I have to implement this description as an algorithm. But I'm super confused on how to tackle the line "The player can jump from pillar i to j iff. i <= j <= i + S and h_j <= h_i + S.

Is it possible someone can try and simplify it for me?

Comment: I recommend a more descriptive title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you are asking for an explanation of that line, not about how to implement it in code.)

> The player can jump from pillar `i` to `j` iff `i < j <= i + S` and `h_j <= h_i + S`.

This means:

- the player can only jump from left to right (`i < j`)
- not further than `S` (`j <= i + S`)
- not higher than `S` (`h_j <= h_i + S`)

Here, `i` seems to be the index of the numbers in your input and `h_i` the number itself. Note that `j` (one of the indices) is not the same as `J` (the maximum number of jumps). ["iff"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) means "if and only if".

Comment: Tobias is it possible you can show me the code too? I've tried but cannot get it to work.

Comment: @David I'll think about it, but it's not that easy... do you have a link to the original problem?